# When installing headless Ubuntu (aka server mode), what ISO is best when the features of cloud-init are not wanted?

Tags: server, system-installation, cloud-init

Am I just a curmudgeon when I find cloud-init annoying?  I don't use "the cloud" for any of my projects yet the Ubuntu server ISO assumes that is my only path!

I wouldn't mind so much if cloud-init would figure out that it isn't "in the cloud" and disable itself.  Instead, I have to figure out how to do some of the most simpliest of tasks (changing the hostname, as an example) via this convoluted process.

In short, how do I get a Ubuntu server installation that doesn't assume I'm going to integrate it with the cloud?

Comment: You can start from the Ubuntu `mini.iso` and add only the program packages that you really want. The `mini.iso` can only install its system in BIOS mode (not in UEFI mode). If you must boot in UEFI mode, there are the Ubuntu Server iso files ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I wish Ubuntu would be more clear that the "server" ISO is really a "cloud server" ISO.  Yes, you can run it outside of the cloud but it isn't designed to do so.